# Why didn't Doc prevent Marty's accident in 1985

Tags: time-travel, back-to-the-future, back-to-the-future-ii

In the begining of Back to the Future Part II, when Doc arrives in 1985 to get Marty and Jennifer back to 2015, he apparently knows about the car accident that ruined Marty's life in the future. This guess can be deduced from the Part III where Doc gives sort of hint to Marty about that accident. Obviously Doc only could find out this event during the first trip in 2015, **before** the mentioned moment.

Why does Doc care about the trouble with Marty's kids in the distant future and ignore the **key event** in Marty's life which should be happened literally the next day? The event most probably caused all further troubles with Marty's family including the above.

No need to send him to the future to fix it. The accident will happen just the day after. So all that's needed is warn Marty of the accident. Then go to 2015 to track the effects. And most likely there will be no need to save Marty's kids.

Answer (score 6):

Probably because it wasn't a simple matter of avoiding one event. The car accident was the ultimate problem Marty encountered from his personality of not wanting to appear a chicken. Even if Doc had prevented the car accident, this wouldn't have changed Marty's personality. He needed to personally change, something only he can effectively change.

My point is that, even if Doc had prevented the car accident, Marty probably would have ruined his life in some other way, possibly killing himself in the attempt to prove he wasn't chicken.

Comment: For all we know, the Doc *did* act to prevent Marty's accident, specifically by bringing him into the future to see what his life was like, using the thing with his kids as an excuse. The Doc *is* a planner...

Comment: @user867 but you're forgetting that he specifically tries to prevent Marty from seeing his future self - if it was up to Doc, he wouldn't have even let Marty know he marries Jennifer, let alone lives in Hill Dale.

Comment: It's possible that the Doc intended Marty to find out about his life through observation of his kids rather than through meeting himself, possibly accompanied by some dramatic exposition on the Doc's part. Or maybe it's all just an incredible coincidence. I must admit this is just speculation at this point.

Comment: @user867 Again, a feasible assumption but it seems unlikely to me

Comment: Oh, yes, it's terribly unlikely. No argument here.

Comment: @N_Soong While it give explanation from viewpoint of the plot development, it doesn't explain Doc's **motivation**. If we assume these arguments it should imply that Doc **foresaw** all events happened with Marty in BttF II-III which help him to grow up as personality. Smells like conspiracy theory.